# python 3.4 mod wsgi get SyntaxError: invalid syntax\r

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

When I run the following code I get a syntax error:

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    result = ChildClass().getValue()
    status = '200 OK'
    output =  result

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    print(output)
    return [output]

class ChildClass(): # define child class
   print('ppp')
   def __init__(self):
      print("Calling child constructor")

   def childMethod(self):
      print('Calling child method')
      #Parentclass().parentMethod()

   def getValue(self):
    # Open database connection
    db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='55118',host='127.0.0.1',database='test')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT * from employees2")
    cursor.execute(query)
    #for (first_name) in cursor:
    return result = cursor.fetchall()
```

It doesn't accept the return : return result = cursor.fetchall()\r SyntaxError: invalid syntax\r

Comment: Remove the `result =` ad the `;` as well.

Comment: i get: mod_wsgi (pid=2304): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py'.
[Mon Aug 10 14:37:25.393918 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 2304:tid 940] [client 127.0.0.1:49548] TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type list found\r

Comment: Under Python 3, a WSGI application must return a byte string as the variable 'output'. It cannot be a Unicode object or some other type.

Comment: I trying to convert it to byte but each time i get different error? how to convert this result to byte?