# TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run a simple "hello world" application using `mod_wsgi` for Python 3. I'm using Fedora 23. Here's my Apache virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    # ServerAlias foo.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias /headers /home/httpd/localhost/python/headers/wsgi.py
    DocumentRoot /home/httpd/localhost/public_html
    ErrorLog /home/httpd/localhost/error.log
    CustomLog /home/httpd/localhost/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

It works fine if I use `mod_wsgi` for Python 2 (`sudo dnf remove python3-mod_wsgi -y && sudo dnf install mod_wsgi -y && sudo apachectl restart`), but I get a 500 internal server error when using Python 3. Here's the error log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=899): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/httpd/localhost/python/headers/wsgi.py'.
TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found
```

**Update**

Using `encode()` (or `encode('utf-8')`) on `str(len(output))` isn't working either. Now I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/httpd/localhost/python/headers/wsgi.py", line 8, in application
    start_response(status, response_headers)
TypeError: expected unicode object, value of type bytes found
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding your strings ? Example: `status.encode()`

Comment: [Under Python 3, a WSGI application must return a byte string as the variable 'output'. It cannot be a Unicode object or some other type.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918319/python-3-4-mod-wsgi-get-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-r#comment51750828_31918319)  <--- I didn't try, didn't use `mod_wsgi` with Apache in a while.

Comment: @Rolbrok: I did actually, forgot to mention. Now I get `TypeError: expected unicode object, value of type bytes found`.

Comment: `status.encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change some of them back, yes? See which ones the error is referring to. Experiment. **Read the docs if all else fails** :)

Comment: @Rolbrok: Same error...

Comment: What about the `response_headers` ? Is there documentation on the subject ?

Comment: [The docs](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) don't seem to be very clear on the subject...

Comment: The docs are also pretty old... Can you try encoding `status`, the strings in `response_headers`, but not `output` ? [More docs](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/).

Comment: I know you're still in "testing" phase, so you can try this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/webservers.html) or [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04) one.

Comment: @Rolbrok: I tried, still got the "expected unicode, got bytes" error. And I've been using the LAMP configuration for quite a while now, I wanted to try out Python (with and without Django) with Apache. I chose mod_wsgi over mod_python or cgi because it works out-of-the-box with Django. :)

Comment: Why do you want to use Python 3 over Python 2 ? Have you tried using the tests from [this repository](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100889/discussion-between-sumit-and-rolbrok).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apparently the variable `output` itself needs to have a bytes string rather than a unicode string. And it needs to change not only for `response_headers`, but for *everywhere `output` is used* (so `str(len(output)).encode('utf-8')` on line 6 wouldn't work, like I'd been trying).

So the solution in my case is:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

(which I found in [one of the tests](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/tests/hello.wsgi) on the official mod_wsgi repo, as suggested by Rolbrok in comments.)

Comment: This one made me grow some gray hairs tonight! I stumbled upon the solution right before coming here at 4:00 AM. Got to be at work in about 3 hours. Just wondering why this is required is there any further reading on this?

Comment: Why is that? I makes things unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 16):

**Background**

The issue is caused because Python 3 defaulted UTF-8, because today, we find that there is a lot of non native English characters, and it is best to accommodate them.  HTTP works only with ASCII characters.  It does not handle UTF-8 well.  Hence, neither Apache,nor mod_wsgi works well with UTF 8.

**Solution**

So, after you prepare the entire html string, you can typecast it using the inbuilt python function - **bytes()**.  This takes a string and gives a byte string.

**Sample Code**

```
html = "This "
html += "is the code"
html = bytes(html, encoding= 'utf-8')
response_header = [('Content-type', 'text/html')]
start_response(status, response_header)
yield html
```